# ionic http request loading timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout, ionic-framework

I am using the following to show a loading screen whenever I am performing a http request however sometimes if there is an error then it will stay loading (because of the backdrop the app becomes unusable). Rather than hide it on every error checker I was wondering if it is possible to call the timeout after 5 seconds?

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
                return config
            },
            response: function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return response
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Following Jess's answer it now looks like this :

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
                return config
            },
            response: function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return response
            },
            responseError: function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return response

            },
            requestError: function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return response
            }
        }
    })
})
```

However I cannot seem to be able to put an alert in the `requestError` to inform the user.

**Question**
How can I implement an alert to notify the user of the error that has occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `responseError` and `requestError` so like this:

```
 responseError: function(responseError) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return responseError
```

and do this again with `requestErro`r,
This is from the angular http interceptors docs

`requestError`: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.

`responseError`: interceptor gets called when a previous interceptor threw an error or resolved with a rejection.

**Edit to answer comment:**

so if you want to throw a alert on `responseError` than a add a `$rootScope.$broadcast('response:error')`

in the responseError function

then in the controller you want to throw the alert in just do a

```
$scope.$on('response:error', function(){throw the error here});
```

you can also do the same for `requestError`

this works because `$broadcast` -- dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes

Comment: Hi Jess, please see my edit regarding adding an alert.

Comment: Hey @Taylorsuk I updated my answer. That should work for you.

Comment: I actually used `$rootScope.$emit` so that I can alert all my errors centrally and pass the `response.error` object - works a charm.